# error: template: "..." is an incomplete or empty template

Tags: go

I'm trying to add a `FuncMap` to my templates, but I'm receiving the following error:

> template: "foo" is an incomplete or empty
>   template

The parsing of templates worked just fine before I used the `FuncMap`, so I'm not sure why it's throwing an error now.

Here is my code:

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "IntToUSD": func(num int) string {
        return decimal.New(int64(num), 2).String()
    },
}

// ...

tmpl, err := template.New(t.file).Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(t.files()...)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
```

`t.files()` just returns a slice of strings that are file paths.

Anyone know what's up?

Comment: is t.file the base name of one of the files in t.files()?  (See requirements in [ParseFiles doc](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ParseFiles))

Comment: Are you saying that `template.New(t.file).ParseFiles(t.files()...)` works fine but `template.New(t.file).Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(t.files()...)` fails?

Comment: @muistooshort No actually I misspoke, `template.ParseFiles(t.files()...)` works properly, it's when I used the `template.New(...)` syntax that it fails.

Comment: @jrefior No it is not, good catch I'll try checking that.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Make sure the argument you pass to `template.New` is the base name of one of the files in the list you pass to `ParseFiles`.

One option is

```
files := t.files()
if len(files) > 0 {
    name := path.Base(files[0])
    tmpl, err := template.New(name).Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(files...)
```

[ParseFiles documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ParseFiles):

> Since the templates created by ParseFiles are named by the base names of the argument files, t should usually have the name of one of the (base) names of the files.

Comment: what if i use **template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(fm).ParseFiles("test.gohtml")** does it work?? answer:-NO but why?

Comment: FYI, it wasn't working on my side because name didn't include the file extension. As soon as I added the extension it worked.

Comment: @RujalShrestha `template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(fm).ParseFiles("test.gohtml")` does work if you use `err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "test.gohtml", data)` instead of `err = tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)`. Basically, a template name has to be specified somewhere.

Comment: One of Go's idiocracies...

Comment: I hate this. why is the templates Name important to it's functionality?? Thanks though.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem. I realized that

```
tmpl, err := template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles("fileName")
```

also works if you use it with

```
err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(wr, "fileName", data)
```

If I use

```
err := tpl.Execute(wr, data)
```

then I should specify the template name in `New()`:

```
tmpl, err := template.New("fileName").Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles("fileName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Template.Must method,

```
templ = template.Must(template.New("fileName").Funcs(fm).ParseFiles("fileName"))
```